# Differential equations stability diagram in Python

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am working with a set of 2 differential equations with 3 parameters, say, dX/dt and dY/dt with parameters A, B and C. I want to make a 2-D diagram for the fixed points of one of the variables, for example, X. In this diagram, I fix the value of A and each dimension corresponds to B and C. Then in the diagram I would have a colour bar depending on the value of the X fixed point. Also, I only want to plot the fixed points if they are stable.

How should I do it? I considered iterating for several values of B and C and creating 3 arrays: one for B values, another for C values, and another for X values (fixed points), which I would only store if the fixed point is stable. How could I compute the fixed points and check their stability, in this case, using Python?

Anyway, is there any more efficient and softer way?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried yet ? Did you write any code

Comment: No. My doubt is about the proper way of doing it, so I am in the planning phase. @NicolasMoreau